# I've added Chapter numbering style but a large space exist between the automatic numbering and the heading text

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

It looks like this:

Chapter I [   large space  ] Problem formulation

this is normal text and the above is really frustrating 
how do i get rid of the large space in between?

Comment: My thesis is due monday, so I'll really appreciate if someone here has an easy-fix to this :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points to post comments. So I am unable to know how you created the numbering style.

However, try reducing the hanging indent. Click where the arrow on the picture and move it to the left.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. This fixed the problem. I did however also find an alternative: on the heading that is causing you trouble, find the heading in the Styles window on your Home tab: right-click and select modify. now, under format, you click on paragraph and can change the indentation. my optimal setting was "hanging" and with 1.02 cm. Hope it helps if anyone else run into this problem :)

Comment: You can mark my answer as solution or not. Or write how you modified the style as an answer.